# Should I make subVIs in preallocated VI as preallocated too in LabVIEW?

Tags: execution, labview, reentrancy

I have got a VI which execution type is set to be as preallocated clone reentrant.
In the VI i have several SubVIs. Should I set the execution type of  SubVIs the same as in the main VI?
[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Setting a VI to be reentrant doesn't automatically make its subVIs reentrant - if it did, this would break some of the use cases for non-reentrant VIs, such as serialising access to single resources or maintaining stored state data between calls. So to decide whether a subVI needs to be reentrant, you just have to consider the same issues as you did when deciding whether the parent VI needed to be reentrant.

I found a good summary of the considerations in [this post by **GregR** on the LAVA forum](https://lavag.org/topic/15656-subvis-calling-subvis-that-need-to-be-reentrant-what-level-needs-to-be-reentrant/?do=findComment&comment=94606), which still holds true as far as I can see (*fully reentrant* was the older LabVIEW term for preallocated clone reentrant):

> - Any VI that maintains state needs to be either non-reentrant or fully 
>     reentrant depending on its requirements for that state.
> - If there are any VIs that truly can't be called at the same time, those should 
>     stay non-reentrant. This could be things like configuration dialogs or file modification. Non-reentrant VIs are one of the easiest ways to serialize access to single instance resources.
> - Any VI that is part 
>     of a performance critical code path probably should be made fully   reentrant. This avoids synchronization points between multiple parallel instances of performance critical code or non-performance critical code getting in the way of performance critical code.
> - Beyond that you can start to favor non-reentrant or shared reentrant to   reduce memory usage.
> - [...] VIs that always execute quickly can be considered for leaving as non-reentrant. Keep in mind that there is a difference between a VI that always executes quickly and one that typically executes quickly. Anything that does asynchronous communication (networking, queues, ...) should be   considered slow, because it could take longer than expected.
> - Making VIs that are called from a lot of places shared reentrant instead of fully reentrant will slightly increase execution time but can greatly 
>     reduce the number of instances required and thus memory usage.

Comment: Thank you for your answer dear nekomatic. As far as I understand I need to make SubVIs to be reentrant too.

Comment: Yes if the subVI might take a long time to execute and you need multiple copies executing at once, or if the subVI is in a time-critical code path and it doesn't cause any memory problems. No if the subVI always executes quickly. I've edited the first paragraph of my answer.

Comment: One additional question. I use Message Queues in the parent SubVI. Should I make them as preallocated too?

Comment: Message Queues from the [Actor Framework](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361P-01/lvcomm/af_message_queue_pal/)? I haven't used that myself but at a guess you shouldn't need to change the reentrancy setting of any standard LabVIEW VIs. Perhaps this should be a new question with a code sample (preferably as a VI Snippet)?

Comment: Queued Message Handler
http://www.ni.com/tutorial/53391/en/

Ok. I will ask another question and place the link here

Comment: [Here is the next question about Queued Message handler VIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50291434/queued-message-handler-vis-in-parent-subvi-which-execution-type-is-set-to-be-as)

Comment: @nekomatic short answer: in general, msg handler subVIs want shared reentranct. Rare cases want preallocated reentrancy.

Comment: @srm you mean that I need to set execution of the Queued message handler SubVIs as shared clone reentrant execution?

Comment: I was about to answer your next question but it seems to have gone... The Queued Message Handler VIs seem to me to have appropriate reentrancy settings out of the box. For example **Enqueue Message**, which should always execute quickly, is non-reentrant but **Dequeue Message**, which waits for a message if there isn't one already in the queue, is preallocated clone reentrant. It's good that you're thinking about this, as timing bugs can be a lot harder to trace than simple data-value bugs, but for most purposes I think you can trust the designers of the framework to have chosen correctly.

Comment: @Henrik As a general rule, yes. I am not actually writing an answer to your question because I don't have the time to do the analysis you're asking for right now. I'm saying use shared reentrancy for QMH subVIs because it is probably right, but if it is wrong, it's the "least wrong", i.e., if it is wrong, it'll cause you some minor performance or memory hiccups that you can probably live with. But it is right most of the time.

Comment: @nekomatic [here is the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50330580/queued-message-handler-vis-in-parent-subvi-which-execution-type-is-set-to-be-as), you can answer there